# MySql Data provider for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, mysql-connector

I recently upgraded from Visual studio 2017 to VS 2022, and i'm facing this problem with an old C# Windows Forms (.Net framework 4.5):
When trying to enstablish a new connection with MySql Db I can not select the MySql Data Source as you can see here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xIZr.png)

I've deleted all MySql products (MySql server, connector ...) and installed the newest version (Connector 8.2.0, MySql installer 8.0.35).
For older Visual Studio versions i know there was MySql for Visual studio but it's not present in the installer anymore.

Thanks